# Why is ngModel non-assignable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, filter, angular-ngmodel

I have a date and i want it to have a filter on it so it would have the format i want for it.

html:

```
<input type="text" id="{{ID}}" ng-style="{color: color}" class="tdate ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="time.date | DatePlaceHolder">
```

filter:

```
function DatePlaceHolder($filter) {
    return function (value) {
        return $filter('date')(value, "dd/MM/yyyy") || "--/--/----";
    }
}
```

It works fine but I keep getting this error:

```
Error: [ngModel: nonassign] Expression 'time.date | DatePlaceHolder' is non-assignable. Element: <input type="text" id="{{ID}}" ng-style="{color: color}" class="tdate ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="time.date | DatePlaceHolder">
```

Comment: You can't use filters on ngModel. Obviously you can't assign model value back to expression `time.date | DatePlaceHolder`. You should use parsers and formatters.

Answer (score 11):

`ng-model` is to bind model with views to take input or display view. you cant use filter on ng-model.

If you want **to display data only**, then you can use ng-bind for non input elements, and ng-value for form elements.

Here is example.

$scope.someValue='Value in controller'

Comment: can i have an example?

Comment: you saved my life